# Type narrowing with lodash _.isNil function doesn't work

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am trying to narrow types with lodash function `isNil(value: any): value is null | undefined;` but apparently, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```js
// ...
const localEnv = process.env.app_env;

if (_.isNil(localEnv) === false) {
// getting TS error: TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    config.env = localEnv;
}

// ...
```

I am using Typescript 4.4.4
with tsconfig compilerOptions: `"strict": true` which by default have `"strictNullChecks": true` which by default associate `undefined` with property `process.env.app_env`.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Try testing with `if(!_.isNil(localEnv))`

Comment: Works! But why?

Comment: Because you are testing only one case (false) and `undefined` left untested. Since undefined is a falsy value `if(!...` also eliminates it.

Comment: So what is strict condition then? I mean this doesn't work: `(_.isNil(localEnv) === false && _.isNil(localEnv) !== undefined)`?

Comment: I think checking explicit equality to `false` is destroying the type guard utility and typescript treating the function as a normal function, not a type guard.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense and I think that could be improved. The issue is that in our project, we are always using strict comparisons, strict checks(same as in question) so `!.isNil(...)` is a potential bug for us. Anyway, Thanks a lot @Eldar I will probably create an issue for this one or try to ask in TS discord channel.